# Using OAuth2.0 with VueJS? How to start?

Tags: oauth-2.0, vuejs2

I am building a third party client/app that needs to authorize a user via OAUTH2 before the protected Resource Server can be accessed.

I am hoping someone can help guide me with the process that I need to undertake to make this happen.

The client app and the Resource Server will both be hosted on a cloud server and managed via PaaS. I will be using a SSO (single sign-on) service to help with environment authorization flow and building the client app using NodeJS and a JavaScript framework (VueJS).

I am required to use a third party/enterprise security authorization server from my employer and not a social network (Google, Facebook, etc).

With the above items laid out, is there a recommended JS library to help me achieve a successful OAuth flow? I've never done this before and not sure where to start. I see PassportJS may be what I am looking for, but not sure if there's an easier library to use for a newbie? **It must be a free, not a paid service.**

Thank you!

Comment: Do you search something like this? https://auth0.com/authenticate/vuejs/oauth2/

Comment: @Markus thanks, but that looks like it's a paid service?

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but I'm looking into https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate